# Confusion in Mode, Mean, Median, PDF, CDF, Var(x) in Rayleigh Distribution versus sigma in the formula

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, variance

[Here the Variance Var(x) formula is given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhTYQ.png)

Here as you can see Var(x) formula

$$Var(X)= \frac{4-\pi}{2}\sigma ^2$$

Now the fact is known that

1)Variance general formula is square of standard deviation = σˆ2

2)and standard deviation = σ

but on LHS of the formula Var(x) is given which is Variance and that is equal to σˆ2 and on RHS also in the formula σˆ2 is included

**how to differentiate between the two - the var(x) on left side and sigma on right side ,is there any distinction here ?
and what does σˆ2 on RHS mean ?**

same goes for other formulae in the pic included - what does σ mean there and is it same as general standard deviation ?

**we also see in gaussian normal distribution ( bells graph ) - var(x) is σ and expectation E(x) or mean is μ
but not in rayleigh , although the notation is used in the rayleigh mean and var(x) formula**

Comment: Read the rest of that wikipedia article. The Rayleigh distribution is related to a pair of uncorrelated normal random variables, each with variance $\sigma^2$ and mean zero. So the $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of those random variables, but only a scale parameter in the Rayleigh distribution. The standard deviation of the Rayleigh distributed random variable is $\sigma$ times a constant factor.

Comment: The table linked at imgur is taken without attribution from the English Wikipedia article.  The *very first line* of that table, which is truncated at the linked image, is "Parameters: scale: $\sigma > 0$."  Here, $\sigma$ is a parameter of the distribution, not the variance of the distribution.

Comment: @Joe could you please elaborate on - pair of uncorrelated normal random variables, each with variance 2 and mean zero - i dont seem to understand this part , i understood the part where you explained that  is a parameter of rayleigh distribution .

Comment: @EricTowers 1) so does this mean the general variance we use the formula in elementary probability and statistics ( high school probability ) - which has simple definitions of mean mode median variance - all of that is related to gaussian normal distribution ?? (because in gaussian distribution those parameters = to the symbol what they depict ) 2) and in reality variance and expectation ( mean ) have a much general and wider definition for different statistical distribution ?

Comment: Distributions are often related to other distributions. As it states in that wikipedia article, if the components of a two dimensional vector are uncorrelated normal random variables with mean zero and the same variance $\sigma^2$, then the magnitude of the vector follows the Rayleigh distribution with scale parameter $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sigma^2$ here is not "variance " but only a parameter of the distribution. To calculate the variance and verify the result in your link use the definition

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=  \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$